# How to change the name of the Special Fields in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

In Crystal Report, I want to change the text of the Special Field "Page N of M" as "Sheet N of M".
How to do this?
I am using Crystal Reports 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.  It would be much easier to:

1. Make a text box of your own
2. Add the special fields "Page Number" and "Total Page Count"
3. Add whatever text you like.

Comment: Yes, I searched a lot. but I couldnt get the answer. Thank you so much for your valuable contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with PowerUser! 
Make a text box with "Sheet" then 
insert SPECIAL FIELD [PAGE NUMBER] then type in text box "of" then insert SPECIAL FIELD [TOTAL PAGE COUNT]

result: SHEET 1 of 1 (depending on the number of docs your working with)

Comment: This post already has an accepted answer that is very comparable to yours. Please explain how it is different or adds value.